# How can I test, if scripting is disabled in my MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to make my mongoDB more secure. I read, that I can start it with --noscripting to deny JavaScript. I tried to verify, that this is working.

When I started the DB like this

```
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --noscripting --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

and then I tried to use the $where-Operator like it is described here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

for example:

> db.myCollection.find({$where: "_id == 1"})

it is returning:

```
Error: error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue no globalScriptEngine in $where parsing",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

Is this the answer, I should expect? Or is it pointing to another failure?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. Stackoverflow is a community for software developers. Your question, however, is about administration. This means it would fit much better on https://dba.stackexchange.com. I nominated your question for migration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior since the [`--noscripting`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--noscripting) option *disables the scripting engine* and all the [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where) operator does is JavaScript evaluation as mention in the official documentation;

> Use the $where operator to pass either a string containing a JavaScript expression or a full JavaScript function to the query system. The $where provides greater flexibility, but requires that the database processes the JavaScript expression or function for each document in the collection. Reference the document in the JavaScript expression or function using either this or obj .

Also the error message is pretty clear.

> ..."$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue no globalScriptEngine in $where parsing"

Note the ***no globalScriptEngine*** part of the message.